# ¿Por qué no se ve aplicado "child selector >" de css únicamente en los elemento <li> directos de un <ul> con id? ul#principal > li

Tags: html, css, selector

¡Hola Comunidad! :)

Tengo una lista no ordenada < ul > con la siguiente estructura:

```
- Frutas
    * Manzana
    * Cereza
- Vegetales
    * Espinaca
    * Apio
    * Cebolla
- Lácteos
```

Quiero aplicar un estilo (font-weight / color) únicamente a los < li > principales (Frutas / Vegetales / Lácteos) sin afectar a los < li > anidados (Manzana / Cereza / Espinaca / Apio / Cebolla).
Aquí el HTML que estoy usando:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link href="miestilo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>LISTAS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="principal">
            <li>Frutas
                <ul>
                    <li>Manzana</li>
                    <li>Cereza</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Vegetales
                <ul>
                    <li>Espinaca</li>
                    <li>Apio</li>
                    <li>Cebolla</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Lácteos</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Esto en el archivo css ("miestilo.css")

```
body {
    background-color: #444;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}

ul#principal > li{
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #EE91AA;
}
```

Al verlo en el navegador el estilo aparece aplicado a todos los < li > incluyendo los que están anidados, hice la prueba en diferentes navegadores y se visualiza igual; también intente agregando un id a los < ul > anidados ya que mi regla css hace referencia al id=principal y con esto esperaba que excluyera a los < ul > anidados pero el resultados no cambió. vi este caso en el siguiente video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iotayt_CC0 (00:46)

¿Les ha ocurrido algo similar usando listas anidadas y el child selector?¿Cómo lo resolvieron?
¡Muchas gracias desde ya! :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con este código indicas que se agregue estas propiedades a todos los "ul" y los hijos que este contenga.

Esta parte del codigo que aplicas "ul#principal > li" se esta realizando una duplicidad en la seleccion, primero le indicas que busque los ul de todo el html y luego que encuentre el id llamado "principal" que tenga hijos "li", lo cual realmente no existe en el html, por eso CSS solo toma el ul y aplica las propiedades a todos indiscriminadamente.

```
ul#principal > li{
font-weight:bold;
color: #EE91AA;
}
```

Recomiendo seas muy especifico en tu CSS con el uso de .clases o #ID

Investiga sobre la metodología BEM (Block, Element, Modifier) te ayudará mucho a tener un CSS ordenado y sin problemas, espero te sea de ayuda.

Para lograr lo que requieres el código deberías de quedar de esta forma:

```css
body {
    background-color: #444;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}

.principal_headerList {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #EE91AA;
}

.principal__elementList {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link href="miestilo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>LISTAS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stackoverflow.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="principal">
            <li class="principal_headerList">Frutas
                <ul class="principal__elementList">
                    <li>Manzana</li>
                    <li>Cereza</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="principal_headerList">Vegetales
                <ul class="principal__elementList">
                    <li>Espinaca</li>
                    <li>Apio</li>
                    <li>Cebolla</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="principal_headerList">Lácteos</li>
        </ul>
        <script src="./stackoverflow.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¡Mil gracias @joseluis18vs! :D
Investigaré sobre la metodología BEM como me indicas, me ha sido de mucha ayuda, gracias.